# Assigning 2 values to radio button element and calling them in PHP

Tags: php, html, forms

I have radio inputs on a form

I am trying to assign them two separate values. One shall be the name of the product, the other is the price of the product.
Then in php I will be totaling the selections.

```
<input type="radio" id="tile1" 
               name="tile" value="Calcatta 12x 24 | 2.99" />
<input type="radio" id="tile2" 
               name="tile" value="Subway 3x12 | 1.99" />
<input type="radio" id="tile3" 
               name="tile" value="Marazza 12x24 | 2.99" />
<input type="radio" id="tile4" 
               name="tile" value="Chicaro 12x12 | 3.99" />
```

For my confirmation email, I need to be able to call on the name of the product.
 For totaling cost, I need to be able to call on the price of the product.

i have tried to search a solution, but I haven't been able to find a specific solution that works.

Comment: Your `<input>` are inside a `<form>`.  This `<form>` will send values to another page via GET or POST.  That page will read the values in `$_GET` or `$_POST` and perform the logic to process these values.  Search for PHP and forms, you will have tutorials on how to set this up (ex https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)

Comment: Radio button is not a good idea to select multiple options, you need to use `CheckBox` in stand of `Radio`

Comment: I know how to set up the php to post. I want to be able to call on each value separately.
like $tile[0] or $tile[1] but it is not working

Comment: We only want one option to be selected is why I chose radio buttons

Comment: So you get a `|` seperated string, so explode it, clean up the unwanted spaces and you will have the 2 parts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the value of `tile` like:

```
$tile    = $_POST['tile']; // e.g. "Calcatta 12x 24 | 2.99"
$details = explode(' | ', $tile);
echo $details[0]; //Calcatta 12x 24
echo $details[1]; //2.99
```

Please note: never ever trust/use user-submitted data like in the example above. Avoid using `$_POST`/`$_GET` variables 'as is'.

Comment: I am using real escape string

Comment: And thank you. I must have read this 6 different times elsewhwere, but it just sunk in with your post

Comment: @ChristopherFutch could you please accept my answer as correct if it resolves your issue? Thanks! :)

Comment: @ChristopherFutch I suppose you did not exploded the string but you're referencing characters in it (0 = c, 1 = a). Use `explode()` first.

Comment: @ChristopherFutch Oh, I see. There's no whitespace in the `value` of your inputs. If that's the case, you should use `explode('|', $walltile);` instead :)

Comment: `<input type="radio" name="walltile" id="tile1" value="calcatta12x24|2.99" />` then php is ` $walltile = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['walltile']);
   
    $walltiledetails = explode(' | ', $walltile);`  I do not understand why its not working

Comment: @ChristopherFutch please take a look at the difference between `' | '` and `'|'`. Separator does matter.

Comment: ok the white space was the problem. Works like a charm. I got like 5 downvotes for this question but dang it was worth it. . I am unable to figure out how to accept your answer as correct. pls helkp me do that now

Comment: got it. thank you @fabrik

Comment: No worries @ChristopherFutch :)